# Navbar bootstrap3 - how to change active item style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to change style for active item. Instead of standard grey border

[image]

I want add some image like this.

[image]

Is there any way for this kind of modification?

Comment: Post your code mate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your code looks like but you can do something like this

```
.navbar #nav > .active > a {
    color: red;
}
```

or  target the class or id however you want

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS pseudo element `::before` in active class.

You may adjust color and position. Sample code below.

```
a.nav-link.active::before {
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    width: 10px;
    background: #000;
    left: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
}
```